# Safari macOS border color

Tags: html, css

For a website I am currently developing, I run into a very big issue on safari only on mac. My input fields do have borders. I am not talking about the well known border radius issue. But as you can see in the picture below, my input fields get a black border from safari. The border however, does dissapear on focus.

[image: search]

I've have tried lots of things, overwriting all the regular properties in css that an input field will get from safari.

```css
.search-posts-by-name {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 400px;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  border-style: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  border-top-right-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  align-self: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 17.5px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  z-index: 3;
}

input.search-posts-by-name::placeholder {
  color: #263238;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-align: left;
}

.form-control-email:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #1B5CB0 inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    background-position: 6px 12px;
}

.form-control-password:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #1B5CB0 inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    background-position: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="search-users" placeholder="Search posts by name" class="search-posts-by-name">
```

Nothing seems to work.
Hope you guys can help me figure out how to fix this.
I am using the most recent version of safari.

UPDATE: the form-control-class clashed with the input and i do not understand why, since is specifically target that class. Does anybody know why and how?

Comment: Without the actual code, there is nothing we can do to help. Please provide [mcve] of your relevant html/css.

Comment: edited it with the actual code, thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce with that code and Safari 11.1, there is no border like your image.

Comment: i've checked it and this is the only code influencing it, i do not use javascript to adjust style properties here either. Has also been tested on an older mac, with a lower version of safari. Same issue

Comment: And if you run the code snippet here in Stackoverflow with your Safari, does it have the border?

Comment: nope, in snippet it does not appear

Comment: So something else on your page is affecting this and the example is not complete. We can not help you without a complete example, sorry.

Comment: @Esko you couldn't be more right. I have found the issue even tho i do not understand it. It is fixed. Thanks you for thinking along. I added the issue to the code in the snippet. Even tho the snippet still doesn’t show the issue

Comment: No problem, glad I could help even a little bit :)